# How to select the latest row from a dataset in ODI

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-data-integrator

My table structure :

```
ID1   ID2   ID3  Value  Last_Update_date
 10    11    12   0.1    21-SEP-17 01.46.12.623580000 PM
 10    11    12   0.2    20-SEP-17 01.46.12.623580000 PM
 10    11    12   0.3    19-SEP-17 01.46.12.623580000 PM
 20    21    22   0.4    01-SEP-17 01.46.12.623580000 PM
 20    21    22   0.5    12-SEP-17 01.46.12.623580000 PM
 20    21    22   0.4    21-SEP-17 01.46.12.623580000 PM
```

I am considering ID1+ID2+ID3 as composite ID and I need to extract the the latest row for each composite key .
Suppose for this combination ,ID1,ID2,ID3 ->10,11,12 my select query should return 10,11,12 0.2 (as 20 sep is the latest ) .

I have tried the below code :

```
SELECT a.ID1 ,
       a.ID2,
       a.ID3 ,
       a.value ,
       a.Last_update_date
FROM   a,
       (SELECT ID1,
               ID2,
               ID3,
               MAX(last_update_date) last_update_date
        FROM   a
        GROUP BY ID1,
                 ID2,
                 ID3
        ) b
WHERE   a.ID1              = b.ID1
AND     a.ID2              = b.ID2
AND     a.ID3              = a.ID3
AND     a.last_update_date = b.last_update_date
```

Is there any better way to write this .
 I will using the code in ODI so I have the option only for simple sql functions like  group by etc .
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe ODI supports window functions...

And your join syntax is bad, really bad, like, never do it again bad. Use explicit joins (not that you need them here at all)

```
select x.*
from
(
select a.*, 
       row_number() over(partition by id1, id2, id3 order by last_update_date desc) rn
from a
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` does not give the same result - it will only return a single row. The OP's query will return multiple rows if they all have the same maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` will not return the same values as you query in the case that you have multiple rows with the same maximum value. You could use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` instead:

```
SELECT ID1,
       ID2,
       ID3,
       value
       Last_update_date
FROM   (
  SELECT ID1,
         ID2,
         ID3,
         value,
         last_update_date
         RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY id1, id2, id3 ORDER BY last_update_date DESC )
           AS rnk
  FROM   a
)
WHERE   rnk = 1
```

However, the direct equivalent of your query using analytic functions is:

```
SELECT ID1,
       ID2,
       ID3,
       value
       Last_update_date
FROM   (
  SELECT ID1,
         ID2,
         ID3,
         value,
         last_update_date
         MAX(last_update_date) OVER ( PARTITION BY id1, id2, id3 )
           AS max_last_update_date
  FROM   a
)
WHERE   last_update_date = max_last_update_date
```